# I was trying to deploy my angular project on github-pages, suddenly the error says, Failed to get remote.origin.url

Tags: angular, git, github, repository

I was trying to deploy my angular project on github-pages, suddenly the error says,

```
Failed to get remote.origin.url (task must either be run in a git repository with a configured origin remote or must be configured with the "repo" option).
```

the command I am trying to execute in project directory is:

```
angular-cli-ghpages -d dist/news-app/ --no-silent
```

I have pushed my latest source code on github repository as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have to add the remote to git with :

```
git remote add origin <github-url>
```

And to see the remotes:

```
git remote -v
```